# How to write in to already opened excel file by using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, openpyxl

I opened a excel file by using the following code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook 

wb = load_workbook('path of the file') 
DriverTableSheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name(name = 'name of the sheet')
```

after that I have to append some values in that excel file..

for that I used the following code

```
DriverTableSheet.cell(row=1, column=2).value="value"
```

But it is not responding. Can u guys please guide how to write / append a data in that excel file and save that excel file

Comment: What do you mean by `not responsive`? What is happening? Any errors?

Comment: What do you mean by "not responsive"? Possibly you forgot to `wb.save('path of the file')`.

Comment: I don't work with python but a short googling and this is what I come up with. Try `DriverTableSheet.Write(1,2,"value")`

Comment: error message is like

   "DriverTableSheet.save('C:\Users\u304080\Desktop\Somesh.xlsx')    
AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'save'"

Comment: hi..tried with "DriverTableSheet.Write(1,2,"value")" also but its not working getting error message as " DriverTableSheet.Write(1,2,"value")
AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'Write'"

Comment: What I wrote is `wb.save('path of the file')`. `DriverTableSheet.save('C:\Users\u304080\Desktop\Somesh.xlsx')` raises `AttributeError` because `DriverTableSheet` is a `Worksheet` object but not a `Workbook` object while `wb` is.